# Outdoor fireplace cracks

Tags: masonry

One section of my outdoor fireplace  cracked ....the ledge all around the chimney. You can dig the mortar out with your finger it's like brown sugar it was built last summer.

Comment: Interesting. Did you have a question? You might [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what makes a good one.

Comment: Contact the people who built it and see if they will acknowledge that it was done poorly and fix it for you free of charge?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. @isherwood is right: we can't answer unless you give us a clear question.